# QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on genavb-dev

Tags: yocto, bitbake

```
WARNING: /home/user1/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp_nxp/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_4.1.15.bb.do_compile is tainted from a forced run
WARNING: /home/user1/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp_nxp/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-imx_2016.03.bb.do_compile is tainted from a forced run
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
WARNING: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on libgstapp-1.0, but it isn't a build dependency, missing gstreamer1.0-plugins-base in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
WARNING: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on gstreamer1.0, but it isn't a build dependency, missing gstreamer1.0 in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
WARNING: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on dbus-lib, but it isn't a build dependency, missing dbus in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
WARNING: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on glib-2.0, but it isn't a build dependency, missing glib-2.0 in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
WARNING: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on libffi, but it isn't a build dependency, missing libffi in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
ERROR: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on genavb-dev [dev-deps]
WARNING: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on genavb-dev, but it isn't a build dependency, missing genavb in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
WARNING: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on readline, but it isn't a build dependency, missing readline in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
WARNING: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA Issue: initscripts rdepends on libpcre, but it isn't a build dependency, missing libpcre in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
ERROR: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: initscripts-1.0-r155 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user1/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp_nxp/bld-agl/tmp/work/imx6qsabreauto-poky-linux-gnueabi/initscripts/1.0-r155/temp/log.do_package_qa.29075
ERROR: Task 1431 (/home/user1/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp_nxp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/initscripts/initscripts_1.0.bb, do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
```

I'm getting these errors for bitbake fsl-image-avb. Some please help me solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does initscripts only ship bash scripts?
If so, add:

`INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "build-deps"`

It specifies the QA checks to skip for a specific package within a recipe.

Comment: I've added custom files to the initscripts. Also I tried with INSANE_SKIP for thr package. It is till showing the same error bro!!

Comment: Did you put the _${PN} at the end?

Comment: In the worst case, add them to `DEPENDS` flag

Comment: `build-deps` sould do it, if not try `DEPENDS` AND `RDEPENDS`

Comment: Thank you very much @David Bensoussan!
I used INSANE_SKIP_genavb-dev = "dev-deps" instead of INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "build-deps" for the previous time. But now, I've modified it as you mentioned and its working.

Comment: BTW, can you please mention the cause of this error, if you have any idea?

Comment: Where were you putting the `INSANE_SKIP`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148848/discussion-between-surendra-nath-and-david-bensoussan).